# telethon.TelegramClient not working when calling from Dash callback

Tags: telegram, plotly-dash, telethon

I am kind of a newbie with dash and I try to call a function that creates a telethon TelegramClient instance and send a message when triggerd by a Dash callback, but it looks like the line

```
client = TelegramClient(phone_number, api, hash)
```

is running forever without any error message
but when I run from outside the dash app just as python script it work fine..

does anyone have an idea to make it work ?

Here is my code :

helper.py :

```
layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Div(
            dbc.NavbarSimple(
            children=[
                dbc.NavItem(dbc.NavLink("Telegram User and Localisation", href='/telegram-exp')),
                dbc.DropdownMenu(
                    children=[
                        dbc.DropdownMenuItem("More pages", header=True),
                    ],
                    nav=True,
                    in_navbar=True,
                    label="Tools"
                ),
            ],
            brand='test',
            color='primary',
            dark=True
            )
        ),
        dbc.Row(
            [
                dbc.Col(html.Div(
                    [
                                dbc.Input(
                                    id='message',
                                    placeholder='message',
                                    n_submit=0,
                                    ),

                                html.P(id='text'),
                ],

                )),
            ]
        ),
    ]
)
@app.callback(
    Output('text', 'data'),
    Input('message', 'n_submit'),
    State('message', 'value'),
    prevent_initial_callback=True
)
def update_loc(inpt, stat):
    return send_message(stat)
```

send.py

```
def send_message(msg):
client = TelegramClient(phone_number, api_ID, API_hash)
async def main():
    await client.send_message('me', msg)
    return msg

with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

I change the code to be more generic but the main question is why TelegramClient running for ever without any error message, and how to solve it..

Thanks

Comment: Telethon uses `asyncio`. This means it must always use the same `asyncio` event loop to work. When there are threads (which Dash likely uses), the same event loop cannot be used, so Telethon won't work. My recommendation is to setup a separate thread dedicated to only run `asyncio` code and then communicate with it via thread-safe queues (there's other questions on this site for how to do that).

Comment: Thanks ! I am not sure to understand you answer, I am not very familiar with multi-threading, can you explain me a bit more, or give me links to these questions?